# Geometrical meaning of orientation on vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orientation

Can any one explain, the geometrical meaning of orientation in a vector space?

Comment: This is a fairly subtle question. The usual definition relies on the _determinant_ of a linear operator, and the fact that an invertible operator has non-zero determinant (or the equivalent). Have you encountered a cryptic formal definition that you're trying to understand? Are you looking for more than "a way of distinguishing space from its mirror image"?

Comment: Yes, I need geometric meaning of that definition.

Answer (score 8):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\Vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}\newcommand{\ve}{\Vec{e}}\newcommand{\vv}{\Vec{v}}\newcommand{\vw}{\Vec{w}}$To ensure we're on the same page algebraically, here are some preliminaries:

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional real vector space. If $(\vv_{i})_{i=1}^{n}$ and $(\vw_{i})_{i=1}^{n}$ are *ordered* bases of $V$, there exists a unique invertible linear operator $T_{\vv}^{\vw}:V \to V$ satisfying
$$
T_{\vv}^{\vw}(\vv_{i}) = \vw_{i}\quad\text{for all $i = 1, 2, \dots, n$,}
$$
and this operator has a well-defined *determinant* $\det T$, a non-zero real number. (The usual definition is to express $T$ as a matrix with respect to an arbitrary basis of $V$ and show the determinant of the resulting matrix does not depend on the choice of basis.)

**Definition**: We say $(\vv_{i})_{i=1}^{n}$ and $(\vw_{i})_{i=1}^{n}$ are *consistently oriented* if $\det T_{\vv}^{\vw} > 0$; otherwise $(\vv_{i})_{i=1}^{n}$ and $(\vw_{i})_{i=1}^{n}$ are *oppositely oriented*.

**Lemma**: "Consistently oriented" is an equivalence relation on the set of ordered bases of $V$.

Fix an *orientation of $V$*, i.e., an ordered basis $B = (\vv_{i})_{i=1}^{n}$. Let's try to understand the geometry carried by the orientation.

Imagine fixing the first $(n - 1)$ elements of $B$. The hyperplane $H_{n}$ spanned by $(\vv_{i})_{i=1}^{n-1}$ may be viewed as a "mirror" that separates $V$. Precisely, if $\vv$ is an arbitrary vector in $V$, one of three things happens:

- Replacing $\vv_{n}$ by $\vv$ gives a consistently ordered basis.
- $\vv \in H_{n}$, so $\{\vv_{1}, \dots, \vv_{n-1}, \vv\}$ is not a basis of $V$.
- Replacing $\vv_{n}$ by $\vv$ gives an oppositely ordered basis.

You can "interpolate" between these three contingencies by allowing $\vv$ to move continuously along a path from $\vv_{n}$ to $-\vv_{n}$. At some point(s), this path must "cross the hyperplane $H_{n}$" or "travel through the mirror", whereupon the orientation changes, i.e., the resulting basis is oppositely-oriented.

There's nothing special about fixing the $n$th vector, or even about fixing all the vectors but one. You can allow each $\vv_{i}$ to vary continuously: As long as the resulting set remains a basis "at each instant", that basis is consistently oriented.

Note that *changing the ordering of the basis elements generally changes the orientation*. For example, swapping the labels of two basis elements changes the orientation. Generally, a re-ordering defines a consistently-oriented basis if and only if the permutation of indices is an even permutation, i.e., can be written as a composition of evenly many transpositions.

---

It's worth pointing out a final subtlety in $\Reals^{3}$: If $(\ve_{i})_{i=1}^{3}$ denotes the standard basis, the (algebraic) ordering of the vectors fixes an orientation, but *we must still pick a conventional geometric representation*, i.e., must choose to depict the standard basis as "right-handed" or "left-handed".